# synchronising lock step execution of threads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have a top level controller, which schedules n sub threads,
and waits for all of them to complete before scheduling them all over again. These threads go on forever, so the threads do not need to be joined.

So the pseudo-code is something like this (assuming n=2):

```
Top:
    loop:
        1. initiate T1 and T2
        2. wait for completion of both T1 and T2
T1: (similarly for T2)
    loop:
        1. wait for lock-1
        2. do something
        3. send completion signal
```

I am thinking of the following code for this, where Top,T1,T2 are
separate threads:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NUM_PROCS 2

pthread_mutex_t m_1, m_2; // for scheduling T1,T2
int count;
pthread_mutex_t m_count; // for completion-signal
pthread_cond_t c_count;
pthread_attr_t attr; // for threads
pthread_t thread[NUM_PROCS+1];

void *Top(void *t) {
    count=0;
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_2);

        // not sure if this the correct way to wait for T1&T2
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_count);
        while(count < 2) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&c_count, &m_count);
        }
        count=0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_count);
    }
}

void *T1(void *t) { // similarly for T2
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_1); // use m_2 for T2
        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_count);
        count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_count);
        pthread_cond_signal(&c_count);
    }
}

void *T2(void *t) {
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_2);
        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_count);
        count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_count);
        pthread_cond_signal(&c_count);
    }
}

int main() {
    int rc;
    int t[NUM_PROCS+1] = {0,1,2}; // thread numbers
    pthread_mutex_init(&m_1, NULL); // initializations
    pthread_mutex_init(&m_2, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&m_count, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&c_count, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_1); // to allow Top to start first
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_2);

    pthread_attr_init(&attr); // initiate the threads
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    rc = pthread_create(&thread[0], &attr, Top, (void *)&t[0]); 
    rc = pthread_create(&thread[1], &attr, T1, (void *)&t[1]); 
    rc = pthread_create(&thread[2], &attr, T2, (void *)&t[2]); 
}
```

My questions on the above code:

1. Is the above code correct?
2. Usually, lock and unlock are both done by the same thread.
   So my solution, of T1 locking m_1 and Top unlocking it,
   seems a bit weird. Is there a better way of doing this?
3. Is semaphore a more efficient way to do this synchronization?
4. Will the code change (except main() of course) if I implement
   this as separate processes with shared memory, instead of as
   threads? And will that be less efficient than the threads version?

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait` will wait forever unless something calls `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_broadcast`. The correct way to wait for the two threads is with `pthread_join`, which `main` is already doing. So it's not clear what `Top` is trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have added pthread_cond_signal() in T1 now. Top,T1,T2 all run forever, so there is really no need to join the threads. So I have deleted that part of the code. Thanks for noting these problems. Now how do I get this code to work?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the code works now. However, I had a few other questions about the efficiency and also porting this to processes. Would you be able to answer them?

Answer (score 1):

A thread that has not locked a pthread mutex may not unlock it. If you need to create a lock that one thread can acquire and another thread can release, you have to do so with your own code. A standard mutex *is not* such a lock.

Comment: Actually the code works after I fixed based on the comment from @user3386109. So looks like I can acquire lock in one thread and release it in another.

Comment: @R71 Undefined behavior is not required to be consistent, it is *undefined*. You may be able to configure your thread library to enable error-checking, or run the code under thread sanitizer or in valgrind, any one of which will be able to tell you that your code is wrong. Anyway, `pthread_barrier_t`.

Comment: @R71 We say something "works" when it does what someone should expect it to do. It would be a mistake to say a car that doesn't start "works" merely because you think the car shouldn't start. Once you understand that a car should start, you should stop describing one that doesn't as a car that "works". Please correct your expectations so that you will realize that the code actually doesn't work -- you merely think it did because you had an incorrect expectation.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Your analogy of the car starting is not a good one, but I get the point - just because it works in my context it does not mean that it is the defined way of doing it. The usage here is for one thread to signal another, so probably a condition variable would be the better way to implement it, right?

Comment: @R71 A condition variable would be a way to implement it. This is *not* a way to implement it and you only think that it "works" because your understanding of what it *should* do is incorrect.